# Allow internet for a private network computer via other computer on the same private network

Tags: internet, iptables

I am newbie in networking, and I would like to share Internet over a computer that has public and private network connection, for a computer that only has a private network connection.

I have a network 10.0.0.0/16 with a subnetwork 10.0.0.0/24.
I have 2 computers on this private network:

- private: it has one IP: 10.0.0.3 on ens10 interface
- gateway: it has one IP: 10.0.0.2 on ens10 interface, and a public IP: 1.2.3.4 on eth0 interface. This has internet access.

What I did till now:
On the gateway computer(as root):

```
sysctl -w net.ipv4.ip_forward=1
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o eth1 -j MASQUERADE
iptables -A FORWARD -i eth1 -o ens10 -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
iptables -A FORWARD -i ens10 -o eth1 -j ACCEPT
```

On the private computer:

```
route add default gw 10.0.0.2
```

I get this response when I am executing this command:

> SIOCADDRT: Network is unreachable

If I try execute this

```
ip route add default via 10.0.0.2
```

I get

> Error: Nexthop has invalid gateway.

My Question is:

How can I force traffic to go through via 10.0.0.2?
Or what I am doing wrong on which computer?

My private network is in Hetzner cloud.

The private computer network configuration by default

```
10.0.0.0/16 via 10.0.0.1 dev ens10 
10.0.0.1 dev ens10 scope link 
xx.yy.169.254 via 10.0.0.1 dev ens10
```

Comment: This is best done with a good router.

Comment: Unless you can make BOTH computers connect to the same router (with a DHCP server for local use) that connects to the internet, google "Network sharing".

Comment: @John my good router *is* a pc

Comment: From a quick look there's nothing obviously wrong. I don't generally need to add default routes doing this. I have a different set up now but I think my old setup was similar.

Comment: The problem here is that for some reason the route for `10.0.0.0/16` is an *indirect* route (i.e. one that has a `via` part). If you are sure that `10.0.0.2` is *actually* directly reachable (i.e. same broadcast domain; no L2 filtering / client isolation whatsoever), add a *direct* route for it before you add the defaut route.

Comment: @TomYan how can I add a direct route for it?

Comment: `ip route add 10.0.0.2 dev ens10`

Comment: Without being able to see the private host's interface configuration, I'd guess that's because the IP address on ens10 has been configured as /32 instead of the expected /24... It's normal for the /16 aggregate route to be indirect, according to the setup description – rather, there should be an *additional* /24 route marking the subnet as local.

Answer (score 0):

Finally how I make it to work(the bolded sections were essential)...

On hetzner admin, I added a route to my network(10.0.0.0/16)m where:

**destination: 0.0.0.0/0 gateway: 10.0.0.2**

-> this is my gateway server IP address. With this configuiration all traffic going to the internet, will goes through my gateway server

On the Gateway server:

```
echo 1 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -s '10.0.0.0/16' -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE
```

On the Private server sitting only the private network:

ip route add default via 10.0.0.1

I added a nameserver /etc/resolv.conf

```
nameserver 8.8.8.8
```

And that I forgot many-many times, to restart the systemd-resolved.service

**systemctl restart systemd-resolved.service**

Thnak you very much for the answears!